# Pass command line arguments to a program saved in file

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line, microsoft-office

I want to pass command line arguments to MS Office programs (Excel, Word, Powerpoint) like below,

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe" "c:\Book1.xlsx" /e/<arg1>`

To able to access them in MS Office plugin event functions

`private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e){}`

Comment: You can create a .bat with whatever [arguments](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-321cf55a-ace4-40b3-9082-53bd4bc10725) you wish. What's the question?

Comment: Do you mean you want a file(call it argumentsfile) that contains a list of filenames, and for each filename, some parameters. And when you double click a file blah.xls then it opens it with those parameters that you have for  specified that file blah.xls should be opened with?   i'm not sure how that'd be done. Maybe it'd involve associating excel files with a program other than excel, and that program will then execute the file in excel, with the correct arguments

Comment: @Raystafarian Did you not read where he wrote "double clicks the Book1.xlsx"

Comment: @Raystafarian also, a bat file wouldn't be great for giving him a choice of what file to open, if he has to browse to that file. Are you suggesting a bat file for every single xls file?  Or a menu for all xls files.. Maybe a it could somehow give a menu for all xls files in the directory

Comment: @barlop yes, I did miss the "click on book1" part. whoops

Comment: one way could be  if it was vbscript and maybe if xls files were associated with "wscript.exe someprogram.vbs" and then the vbscript looks at the parameter which is the filename and determined what parameters to run the xls file with  Another way would be perhaps if you associated xls files with something like `cmd blah.bat`  (maybe cmd /k or /c) ,  somehow such that blah.bat looks at %1 and sees the xls file

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I have updated the question. Please let me know